# why psycopg2 can not insert string like '\x00'?

Tags: python, psycopg2

When I use **psycopg2** insert data to **PostgreSQL**, I can not insert string which contains '\x00'.

Here is my code:

```
>>> import psycopg2
>>> import psycopg2.extensions
>>> conn = psycopg2.connect(database='test')
>>> curs = conn.cursor()
>>> print curs.mogrify('insert into test values (%s, %s)', 
        ('hello, buddy', 'str\x00str'))
>>> curs.close()
>>> conn.close()
```

I can get string like this:

```
>>> ...
>>> print curs.mogrify('insert into test values (%s, %s)', 
...    ('hello, world', 'str\x00str'))
insert into test values ('hello, world', 'str')
>>> ...
```

So, where is '\x00str'?

But, in **psycopg2**, I find something about 
[unicoding-handling](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#unicode-handling).

It shows ['\x01' - '\xff] works.

Code like:

```
>>> ...
>>> print curs.mogrify('insert into test values (%s, %s)', 
...    ('hello, world', 'str\x01\x02\x03...\xffstr'))
insert into test values ('hello, world', 'str\x01\x02\x03...\xffstr')
>>> ...
```

[**Question**]: where is '\x00str'? How can I make the string '\x00' work in psycopg2?

Comment: have you try '\\x00' ? it seems '\x00' may end the str

Comment: I tried '\\x00'.It works. But, when '\x00\x01' become '\\x00\\x01', their length is not equal.

Comment: \x actually means something in python, the hex; say \x00 == 0, \x0e == Oct 15; so len('\x00') = 1, len('\\x00') = 4; '\\x00' actually means the string you want to save

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to insert a character with value 0 in the middle of the string and PostgreSQL doesn't support that for character data (libpq returns strings \0-terminated and we have no way to discriminate your \0 from the real one). If you want to insert arbitrary data (including 0) use a bytea column and the psycopg2 Binary adapter.

See http://www.psycopg.org/psycopg/docs/module.html#psycopg2.Binary